# How to use like in XPath?

Tags: xpath, operator-keyword

I have a page that searches with filters. I have this code for example,

```
xmlTempResultSearch = xmlResidentListDisplay.selectNodes("//PeopleList/Row[@LastName != '"+txtSearch.value+"']");
xmlTempResultSearch.removeAll();
```

This selects the data that is not equal to the LastName inputted on the `txtSearch` textbox and then removes them from the result set so that its filtered to equal the last name on the `txtSearch` textbox.

My problem with this code is that it should be equal (=) to the `txtSearch`.value, what I want is that I want the result set **LIKE** the `txtSearch.value`. What happens on my page is that when I type '`santos`' on the txtSearch textbox, its result set is all those last names with '`santos`'. But when I type '`sant`', nothing appears. I want the same result set with '`santos`' because it all contains 'sant'

Answer (score 17):

**You can use all of the XPath (1.0) string functions. If you have XPath 2.0 available, then you can even use RegEx**.

**[`contains()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-contains)**

**[`starts-with()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-starts-with)**

**[`substring()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring)**

**[`substring-before()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring-before)**

**[`substring-after()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring-after)**

**[`concat()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-concat)**

**[`translate()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-translate)**

**[`string-length()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-string-length)**

**There is no **[`ends-with()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-ends-with)** in XPath 1.0, but it can easily be expressed with this XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
substring($s, string-length($s) - string-length($t) +1) = $t
```

**is `true()` exactly when the string `$s` ends with the string `$t`.**

Answer (score 4):

You can use start-with function and not function. Reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

```
xmlTempResultSearch = xmlResidentListDisplay.selectNodes("//PeopleList/Row[not(starts-with(@LastName,'"+ txtSearch.value +"'))]");
```

Comment: Link is rotten, fyi

Answer (score 4):

you can use contains() function of XPath:

```
xmlTempResultSearch = xmlResidentListDisplay.selectNodes("//PeopleList/Row[not(contains(@LastName,'"+txtSearch.value+"'))]");
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. I was searching for 'bro' since the last name I want to get is 'Broerman'. I got an error that says:

Error: Expected token ']' found 'NAME'.

//PeopleList/Row[not-->contains<--(@LastName, 'bro')]

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, this should be `not(contains(...))`