# String Functions in JSONPath

Tags: c#, json, xpath, json.net, jsonpath

I'm using [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)'s [SelectToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) method to query JSON using [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) with expressions like:

```
JToken acme = o.SelectToken("$.Manufacturers[?(@.Name == 'Acme Co')]");
```

-- http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm

**Does JSONPath support XPath style String Functions?**
By String Functions, I mean those described in [How to use like in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488213/how-to-use-like-in-xpath#12488839)

For example, is there syntax for the [`contains()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) method?

I've tried:

```
o.SelectToken("$.Manufacturers[?(contains(@.Name, 'Acme')]");
```

but JSON.Net complains of a syntax error (it doesn't like `contains`).

Comment: If by "JSONPath" you mean "the JSONPath supported by SelectToken and SelectTokens in Json.NET", the answer looks to be "no".  If it did, there would be an appropriate `ScanFilter` [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/tree/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JsonPath), but there isn't.  [`QueryFilter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JsonPath/QueryFilter.cs) is closest but [QueryExpression](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JsonPath/QueryExpression.cs) doesn't have it.

Comment: @dbc - Thanks for checking the source.  I guess you're saying if I want it, I'll need to build it?

Comment: Or find some other package that does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json.NET [Release 11](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2018/02/22/json-net-11-0-release-1-net-standard-2-0-jsonconverters-json-path-and-more) introduced the [regex operator](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/RegexQuery.htm) `=~` for JSONPath queries.  Using it you can do string pattern matching including `contains()` matches.  For example:

- To match a value containing the string `Acme` use `=~ /Acme/`:

  ```
  o.SelectToken("$.Manufacturers[?(@.Name =~ /Acme/)]")
  ```
- To match a value containing the **word** `Acme`, bracket it with `\b`:

  ```
  o.SelectToken("$.Manufacturers[?(@.Name =~ /\\bAcme\\b/)]")
  ```
- To do a **case-insensitive** match on a string containing `acme`, preface the case-insensitive portion with `(?i)`:

  ```
  o.SelectToken("$.Manufacturers[?(@.Name =~ /(?i)acme/)]")
  ```

  `(?-i)` ends case-insensitive matching.
- To match a value that **does not contain** Acme, use `=~ /^(?!.*Acme).*$/)`:

  ```
  o.SelectToken("$.Manufacturers[?(@.Name =~ /^(?!.*Acme).*$/)]")
  ```

  See: *[C# Regex to match a string that doesn't contain a certain string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1318279)*.
- To match strings **starting with** `Acme`, insert `^` at the beginning of the regex:

  ```
  o.SelectToken("$.Manufacturers[?(@.Name =~ /^Acme/)]")
  ```
- To match strings **ending with** `Acme`, add `$` at the end of the regex:

  ```
  o.SelectToken("$.Manufacturers[?(@.Name =~ /Acme$/)]")
  ```
- To match strings with a **specified length `N`**, use `=~ /(?s)^.{N}$/)`:

  ```
  o.SelectToken("$.Manufacturers[?(@.Name =~ /(?s)^.{7}$/)]")
  ```

  Here `(?s)` specifies [single line mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regexoptions-singleline) (which forces newlines to be included in the character count), `.` matches any character, the [quantifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions) `.{7}` requires exactly 7 matches of the preceding token `.`, and `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of the string (which prevents the regex from matching strings longer than 7 characters).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oVbjHR).