# Pull all of the child XML nodes in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server 2014 database that stores 2 million XML files. The XML file looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-16'?>
<PROJECTS xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
    <row>
        <APPLICATION_ID>7975883</APPLICATION_ID>
        <ACTIVITY>N01</ACTIVITY>
        <ADMINISTERING_IC>HL</ADMINISTERING_IC>
        <APPLICATION_TYPE xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ARRA_FUNDED>N</ARRA_FUNDED>
        <PIS>
           <PI>
              <PI_NAME>MICHEL, MARY Q</PI_NAME>
              <PI_ID>3704353</PI_ID>
           </PI>
           <PI>
              <PI_NAME>SMITH, ROBERT B</PI_NAME>
              <PI_ID>3704354</PI_ID>
           </PI>
           <PI>
               <PI_NAME>DOE, JOHN A</PI_NAME>
               <PI_ID>3704353</PI_ID>
            </PI>
        </PIS>
        <ORG_DUNS>600044978</ORG_DUNS>
        <ORG_COUNTRY>UNITED STATES</ORG_COUNTRY>
        <ORG_DISTRICT>08</ORG_DISTRICT>
        <ORG_ZIPCODE>208523003</ORG_ZIPCODE>
    </row>
</PROJECTS>
```

My problem is that I want to pull all of the PI values based upon the `ORG_DUNS` numbers in a stored procedure. So the code that I have is:

```
SELECT 
    APPLICATION_ID,     
    nref.value('.','varchar(max)') TERM 
INTO 
    ADMIN_MUSC_RePORTER_TERMS                   
FROM 
    [ADMIN_Grant_Exporter_Files_XML] 
CROSS APPLY  
    XMLData.nodes('//PIS/PI') AS R(nref)
WHERE
    RECID = 1
```

And that work fine when I use a WHERE cause based up another field in the database but if I need to reference a node in the xml file that's where I'm having a problem. I need to pull all the the XML files that have ORG_DUNS equal to 600044978 and I know that the `nref.value('ORG_DUNS[1]', 'varchar(max)')` does not exist because of the cross apply.

```
SELECT 
    APPLICATION_ID,     
    nref.value('.','varchar(max)') TERM 
INTO 
    ADMIN_MUSC_RePORTER_TERMS                   
FROM 
    [ADMIN_Grant_Exporter_Files_XML] 
CROSS APPLY
    XMLData.nodes('//PIS/PI') as R(nref)
WHERE
    nref.value('ORG_DUNS[1]', 'varchar(max)') = '600044978'
```

So how can I get all of the PI nodes using the ORG_DUNS as my WHERE? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Cross Apply statement to include the filter logic in the XPath:

```sql
CROSS APPLY XMLData.nodes('//PIS[../ORG_DUNS/text() = ''600044978'']/PI') AS R(nref)
```

To explain, `//PIS[../ORG_DUNS/text() = ''600044978'']/PI` says:

- `//PIS` - find all elements called PIS
- `[`...`]` - filter the returned elements for those matching this condition
- `../ORG_DUNS/text() = ''600044978''` - Condition: the `PIS`'s parent element's `ORG_DUNS`'s text value equals `600044978`.
- Then return the child `PI` elements of any matching `PIS` elements.

---

**Update per comments**

Full SQL, including PI and PI_ID as separate values:

```sql
SELECT 
    APPLICATION_ID     
    , nref.value('(./PI_NAME/text())[1]','varchar(max)') PI 
    , nref.value('(./PI_ID/text())[1]','varchar(max)') PI_ID
INTO 
    ADMIN_MUSC_RePORTER_TERMS                   
FROM 
    [ADMIN_Grant_Exporter_Files_XML] 
CROSS APPLY 
    XMLData.nodes('//PIS[../ORG_DUNS/text() = ''600044978'']/PI') AS R(nref)
WHERE
    RECID = 1
```

Notes:

- `./PI_NAME` - from the currently selected element (i.e. the one refered to by the `nref` column; which is pointing at a `PI` element), take its child element, `PI_NAME`.
- `/text()` - from the `PI_NAME` element, take its child text element (strictly this is not required, since when pulling back the value & converting to an varchar we'd get the same result; but I like to be explicit).
- `(`...`)[1]` - return a singleton.  i.e. we only want 1 value back, even if there were multiple `PI_NAME` elements under the current `PI`.  By putting brackets around our expression we're saying "for all values returned by this expression"; and `[1]` says take the first result (since XPATH uses one-based indexes rather than zero-based as most other languages would).

---

**Filtering with a variable**

Anticipating your next issue; i.e. "How do you change the number at runtime without building dynamic SQL?", the answer's to use the [sql:variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-variable) function:

```sql
declare @DunningNumber int = 600044978 --9 digit code http://www.dnb.com/duns-number.html; so can easily hold in an int: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql

SELECT 
    APPLICATION_ID     
    , nref.value('(./PI_NAME/text())[1]','varchar(max)') PI 
    , nref.value('(./PI_ID/text())[1]','varchar(max)') PI_ID
INTO 
    ADMIN_MUSC_RePORTER_TERMS                   
FROM 
    [ADMIN_Grant_Exporter_Files_XML] 
CROSS APPLY 
    XMLData.nodes('//PIS[../ORG_DUNS/text() = sql:variable("@DunningNumber")]/PI') AS R(nref)
WHERE
    RECID = 1
```

Comment: This works great and is fast but if I need to change my select statement so I get both the PI and the PI_ ID as seperate values like SELECT 
    APPLICATION_ID,     
    nref.value('.','varchar(max)') PI,  nref.value('.','varchar(max)') PI_ID.  How can I do it?.  I know that was not in the original question but I screwed up

Comment: No worries; almost exactly what you've got already, only tweaked slightly: `nref.value('(.\PI_ID\text())[1]','varchar(max)') TermId, nref.value('(.\Name\text())[1]','varchar(max)') Term`

Comment: Yeah yeah- that was my next question(Smile)  but here is one more how about searching for a PI's Name with only a portion of the node.  Such as the node is "Alberg, Albert J" and I want to search for "ALBERG"

Comment: `Contains`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12488839/361842 \ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/functions-on-string-values-contains.  `XMLData.nodes('//PIS[../ORG_DUNS/text() = sql:variable("@DunningNumber")]/PI[contains(./PI_NAME/text(), sql:variable("@PartialName")]')`

Comment: Thank you very much- this will help the researchers at the Cancer Center at the Medical University of SC-- thanks again

Comment: Sorry still need a little help-- I'm getting a syntax error and don't know how to tweak it. XQuery [ADMIN_Grant_Exporter_Files_XML.XMLData.nodes()]: ',' or ')' expected

Comment: I think that's my mistake, sorry; looks like I missed a close parenthesis above: `XMLData.nodes('//PIS[../ORG_DUNS/text() = sql:variable("@DunningNumber")]/PI[contains(./PI_NAME/text()‌​, sql:variable("@PartialName"))]')`

Comment: Thanks for all of your help

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to first grab multiple levels in the document using multiple CROSS APPLY clauses.  So first, starting from the root grab all the '/PROJECTS/row' and then use a relative path from each of those 'PIS/PI'.

Like this:

```
declare @t table(id int identity, APPLICATION_ID int default (2), XmlData xml)

insert into @t(XmlData) values (
'<PROJECTS xmlns:xsi=''http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance''>
<row>
<APPLICATION_ID>7975883</APPLICATION_ID>
<ACTIVITY>N01</ACTIVITY>
<ADMINISTERING_IC>HL</ADMINISTERING_IC>
<APPLICATION_TYPE xsi:nil="true"/>
<ARRA_FUNDED>N</ARRA_FUNDED>
<PIS>
      <PI>
        <PI_NAME>MICHEL, MARY Q</PI_NAME>
        <PI_ID>3704353</PI_ID>
      </PI>
<PI>
        <PI_NAME>SMITH, ROBERT B</PI_NAME>
        <PI_ID>3704354</PI_ID>
      </PI>
<PI>
        <PI_NAME>DOE, JOHN A</PI_NAME>
        <PI_ID>3704353</PI_ID>
      </PI>

</PIS>
<ORG_DUNS>600044978</ORG_DUNS>
<ORG_COUNTRY>UNITED STATES</ORG_COUNTRY>
<ORG_DISTRICT>08</ORG_DISTRICT>
<ORG_ZIPCODE>208523003</ORG_ZIPCODE>
</row>
</PROJECTS> '),(
'<PROJECTS xmlns:xsi=''http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance''>
<row>
<APPLICATION_ID>7975883</APPLICATION_ID>
<ACTIVITY>N01</ACTIVITY>
<ADMINISTERING_IC>HL</ADMINISTERING_IC>
<APPLICATION_TYPE xsi:nil="true"/>
<ARRA_FUNDED>N</ARRA_FUNDED>
<PIS>
      <PI>
        <PI_NAME>MICHEL, MARY Q</PI_NAME>
        <PI_ID>3704353</PI_ID>
      </PI>
<PI>
        <PI_NAME>SMITH, ROBERT B</PI_NAME>
        <PI_ID>3704354</PI_ID>
      </PI>
<PI>
        <PI_NAME>DOE, JOHN A</PI_NAME>
        <PI_ID>3704353</PI_ID>
      </PI>

</PIS>
<ORG_DUNS>600044979</ORG_DUNS>
<ORG_COUNTRY>UNITED STATES</ORG_COUNTRY>
<ORG_DISTRICT>08</ORG_DISTRICT>
<ORG_ZIPCODE>208523003</ORG_ZIPCODE>
</row>
</PROJECTS> ')

select APPLICATION_ID,      
pinode.value('PI_NAME[1]','varchar(max)') PI_NAME,
pinode.value('PI_ID[1]','varchar(max)') PI_ID           
FROM @t 
cross apply XMLData.nodes('/PROJECTS/row') as r(rownode)
cross apply rownode.nodes('PIS/PI') as p(pinode)
where rownode.value('ORG_DUNS[1]','varchar(max)') = '600044978'
```